# Is it possible to have the Navigation bar Transparent Until the user expands the navigation bar on the Mobile Version?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

**My Problem Scenario:** The navigation bar is transparent on the mobile version of the site so the user can see the banner and the navigation bar is on the banner. Once the user clicks on the navigation bar, it expands and the navigation bar is no longer transparent.

**Problem:** I am not sure how to do this. I am able to make the navigation bar transparent but when I select the navigation bar on the mobile version, it remains transparent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

**UPDATE**

The code below is done in ColdFusion and is the navigation bar. I reference an example I saw and just added what I needed/removed what I didn't.

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 no-padding-left no-padding-right">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse no-padding-left">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <br />
                                    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control btn-standard" value="#HTMLEditFormat($.event('keywords'))#" placeholder=" Site Search" />
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-standard navKeywordsSubmit">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <cf_CacheOMatic key="dspPrimaryNav">
                                        <!--- 
                                            For information on dspPrimaryNav(), visit:
                                            http://docs.getmura.com/v6/front-end/template-variables/document-body/
                                        --->
                                        #$.dspPrimaryNav(
                                            viewDepth=0
                                            , id='navPrimary'
                                            , class='nav navbar-nav nav-nowrap ignore'
                                            , displayHome='never'
                                            , closeFolders=false 
                                            , showCurrentChildrenOnly=false
                                            , liHasKidsClass='dropdown'
                                            , liHasKidsAttributes=''
                                            , liCurrentClass=''
                                            , liCurrentAttributes=''
                                            , liHasKidsNestedClass='dropdown-submenu'
                                            , aHasKidsClass='dropdown-toggle'
                                            , aHasKidsAttributes='role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="##"'
                                            , aCurrentClass=''
                                            , aCurrentAttributes=''
                                            , ulNestedClass='dropdown-menu'
                                            , ulNestedAttributes=''
                                            , aNotCurrentClass=''
                                            , siteid=$.event('siteid')
                                        )#
                                    </cf_CacheOMatic>
                                    <script>
                                        $(function(){
                                            $(#serializeJSON($.getCurrentURLArray())#).each(
                                                function(index, value){
                                                    $("##navPrimary [href='" + value + "']").closest("li").addClass("active");
                                                }
                                            );
                                        })
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                                <!--- /search --->
                            </div><!--- /.row --->
                        </div>
                    </div><!--- /.navbar-collapse --->
                </div>
            </div><!--- /.row --->
```

Comment: Hey Jaegerninja can you post your source code. Without it it's hard for developers to understand what's happening around your code.

Comment: @AshishTalreja Thank you. I will be posting the code shortly.

Comment: @AshishTalreja I have added the code

Comment: you did not add your css code? please share your site url